# Matlab - Cannot replace the icon Matlab by another

Tags: matlab

I can not replace the icon Matlab by another. I have yet to try several code recover on the internet, but it's always the same thing, the Java icon appears and sometimes none are displayed.

Would you another track?

thank you

Here one of the tested codes:

```
warning('off','MATLAB:HandleGraphics:ObsoletedProperty:JavaFrame');
jframe=get(hObject,'javaframe');
jIcon=javax.swing.ImageIcon('icon.png');
jframe.setFigureIcon(jIcon);
initialize_gui(hObject, handles, false);
```

Comment: Please provide more context. Which icon for what and where (i.e., what is your `hObject`)? Are you trying to do [this](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/584)? It's probably a bad idea. The figure windows on OS X (R2013a) don't even have icons unless you minimize them. No idea about other OSes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you show works for me. Are you sure the 'icon.png' file is located in the correct folder? Try specify the full path to the image:

```
jIcon = javax.swing.ImageIcon(fullfile(pwd,'icon.png'))
```